# Hydronium ion concentration to compare pH values

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, ph

I'm having a bit of trouble with this question:

> Which has a higher $\mathrm{pH}$ value, $\pu{0.001 M}$ $\ce{HCl}$ or $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{CH3COOH}$ $(K_\mathrm{a} = \pu{1.8E-5})?$

I have calculated that for the $\ce{HCl}$ solution (since it's a strong acid) the $[\ce{H3O+}] = \pu{0.001 M}.$

Then, for the $\ce{CH3COOH}$ solution I got $[\ce{H3O+}] = \pu{1.33E-3 M}$ (by solving a quadratic equation).

Since the $\ce{CH3COOH}$ has a higher concentration of hydronium ions, doesn't this mean that it will have a lower $\mathrm{pH}$ than the other solution? I'm confused because the answer says it's the other way around.

Comment: The concentrations look correct (next time please show your calculations and note that there is no zero in $\ce{H3O+}$), so you end up with pH 3.00 for HCl and pH 2.88 for acetic acid. What does the answer say, exactly? Could there be a typo?

Comment: The HCl solution has the higher pH value. The acetic acid solution has the higher concentration of hydrogen ions. What exactly did the answer key say?